# Delphi TStringGrid multi select, determining selected rows

Tags: delphi, rows, selected, tstringgrid

Is there anyway to determine which rows are currently selected in a multi-select `TStringGrid`, or a `TCustomGrid` for that matter.  A property would be ideal.

I know that there is the `gdSelected` property that gets set in the `DrawCell` event,

```
procedure DrawCell(ACol, ARow: Longint; ARect: TRect; AState: TGridDrawState);
```

I can check `AState` for `gdSelected`, and keep track of this in an array somewhere, but this seems kludgey.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are talking about a range-select string grid, that is, a string grid with `goRangeSelect` in `Options`. Then you can use the  `Selection` property. This is (essentially) a `TRect` in which you can find the upper-left and lower-right cell in the range selection.

Comment: I don't think this will work, the selected rows are not necessarily contiguous.

Comment: @user746911: No, I assumed that there is no 'extended select' (as in Ctrl-clicking individual cells). It seems to me, however, that the `TStringGrid` does not support extended select. (If it does -- how in the world do you enable it?!)

Comment: AFAICT, @Andreas is right. The standard `TStringGrid` doesn't support non-contiguous selections. `TDBGrid` does, however, by keeping a list of bookmarks of selected rows (`TDBGrid.SelectedRows` property).

Comment: Ah, I see, you are both right, thanks, TStringGrid.selection.bottom and TStringGrid.selection.top work perfectly for this. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Oooh, I'm use `StringGrid.Selection.BottomRight.Y` to determine rows and `StringGrid.Selection.BottomRight.X` for columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use string grid selection property `StringGrid.Selection.top` will give you the top selected row, `StringGrid.Selection.bottom`will give you the end selected row, where the selection stops.

Example:

If you select from row 3 to row 6 in a string grid then`StringGrid.Selection.top` will give you 3 as an output value `StringGrid.Selection.bottom` will give you 6 as an output value, and remaining values you can get by iterating from the top to bottom.